# React - read an attribute or a prop of a parent component from a child that is placed n° level of nesting deep without context or props drilling

Tags: reactjs

How to "read" an attribute or a prop of a parent component from a child that is placed n° level of nesting deep

**REQUISITE: Without using a context or props drilling**

is there a trick? something like a DOM element search

```
document.querySelectorAll
document.getElementBy...
ReactDOM.finddomnode
ref
```

Comment: In theory you could give some HTML Element an ID an read the value of the DOM element using that ID if that's what you're proposing, but that's just madness and defeats the purpose of React. What's wrong with Context API or just passing props down?